# React Native - Luanch storyboard not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm trying to upload my app to the apple store and i'm getting this error. 
I don't think my react native ever started with a storyboard and i don't see anything regarding a storyboard on the reactnative documentation either.

[image: error]

[image]